# Elixir: Selectable Probability Struct Attribute

Tags: elixir

Given a list of structs, is there a way I can alter a probability attribute based upon a predetermined indicator (say game difficulty)? This probability attribute is the probability of the room being selected at random.

My current probability attribute is set and is a nightmare to constantly update. Now that I want to introduce an outside setting that will adjust these values I need to completely redesign how this probability is set. See below for my current setup:

```
defmodule Sandbox do
  defstruct description: nil, chance: nil

  def all, do: [
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 1",
      chance: 1..40
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 2",
      chance: 41..60
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 3",
      chance: 61..100
    },
  ]

  def random do
    rand = Enum.random(1..100)
    Enum.find(all(), fn %{chance: chance} -> rand in chance end)
  end
end
```

Question

1. How can I turn my current setup into one that adjusts the struct attribute "chance" based upon a predetermined setting (game_difficulty = easy, medium, or hard) and will return the randomly selected Sandbox?

Comment: How do you want the probabilities to change for different difficulties? I guess you could store 3 probabilities in each struct for easy, medium, and hard, and then choose that in `random`.

Comment: @Dogbert The probabilities would just adjust up or down based on the difficulty setting. Having a different attribute for each setting should work fine actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd store the probabilities of each difficulty in each struct and then make `random` accept the difficulty level:

```
defmodule Sandbox do
  defstruct description: nil, easy: nil, medium: nil, hard: nil

  def all, do: [
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 1",
      easy: 1..40,
      medium: 1..50,
      hard: 1..60,
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 2",
      easy: 41..60,
      medium: 51..80,
      hard: 61..90,
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 3",
      easy: 61..100,
      medium: 81..100,
      hard: 91..100,
    },
  ]

  def random(difficulty) do
    rand = Enum.random(1..100)
    Enum.find(all(), fn s -> rand in Map.get(s, difficulty) end)
  end
end

IO.inspect Sandbox.random(:easy)
IO.inspect Sandbox.random(:medium)
IO.inspect Sandbox.random(:hard)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use percentage chances to select a room based on difficulty:

```
defmodule Sandbox do
  defstruct description: nil, chance: nil

  def all, do: [
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 1",
      chance: %{easy: 75, medium: 40, hard: 10}
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 2",
      chance: %{easy: 100, medium: 100, hard: 100}
    },
    %Sandbox{
      description: "Description 3",
      chance: %{easy: 100, medium: 50, hard: 10}
    },
  ]

  def random_by_difficulty(rooms, difficulty) do
    mark = Enum.random(1..100)

    rooms
    |> Enum.filter(fn room -> room.chance[difficulty] >= mark end)
    |> Enum.random()
  end
end
```